# @ContentChildren is not being populated when parent render items using ng-content

Tags: angular

I have three components: Panel, PanelGroup (ul) and PanelItem (li):

**Panel:**

```js
@Component({
selector: "panel",
directives: [PanelGroup,PanelItem],
template: `
  <panel-group>
    <ng-content select="panel-item"></ng-content>
  </panel-group>
`})

export default class Panel {}
```

**PanelGroup:**

```js
@Component({
selector: "panel-group",
directives: [forwardRef(() => PanelItem)],
template: `
  <ul>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  </ul>`
})

export default class PanelGroup {
  @ContentChildren(forwardRef(() => PanelItem)) items;

  //I need to access children here and modify them eventually:
  ngAfterContentInit() {
    console.log(this.items.toArray()); //the array is always empty
  }
}
```

**PanelItem:**

```js
@Component({
selector: "panel-item",
directives: [forwardRef(() => PanelGroup)],
template: `
  <li>
    <span (click)="onClick()">
        {{title}}
    </span>
    <panel-group>
        <ng-content select="panel-item"></ng-content>
    </panel-group>
  </li>`
})

export default class PanelItem {
  @Input() title = 'SomeTitle';
}
```

As seen in the above example I try to get the content children inside the **PanelGroup** component, however the collection is always empty. Also tried to add selector to the 'ng-content' inside it - in this case the children are never rendered which is bit weird.

Am I missing something?

Here is plunk:

- [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/tKjmqYhTZOfSYfAfXCtJ?p=preview)

Comment: Looks like a bug to me.

Comment: Created issue https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8937

Answer (score 20):

Use `descendants: true`:

```
@ContentChildren(forwardRef(() => PanelItem), {descendants: true}) items;
```

See also [angular 2 / typescript : get hold of an element in the template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32693061/angular-2-typescript-get-hold-of-an-element-in-the-template/35209681#35209681)

Comment: Well this saved my bacon

Comment: I have tried to modify the existing demo and it does not work. Could you check again ?

Comment: @javaLearner can you please create a reproduction in http://stackblitz.com?

Comment: As you can see, items.length is still 0. I wonder if I miss something?

Comment: Why did you use such an old Angular version? http://stackblitz.com/ would make this much easier. Just click Angular and you get a fully set up project.

Comment: Because the panel component is the one they are projected to http://plnkr.co/edit/pfKONBv13GhIt8cpP7LU?p=preview

Comment: I'm having the same issue with Angular 12. I'm using forward ref, descendants:true and I'm checking in ngAfterContent init the list is empty.

Answer (score 0):

I am having a similar issue but it seems this one can also be solved by removing the select option from the panel-item. I assume since select='panel-item' is looking for only  content but there is a Nested Object as content. If you remove the restriction (in the plunk example) it shows it.